# Как правильно: ОТ или ИЗ?

Tags: орфография

Я получил письмо от Министерства финансов, или же — я получил письмо из Министерства финансов?

Answer (score 2):

"От" может быть только в случае, если отправитель - министерство финансов (в подписи так и написано). А если отдел какой или работник, пусть даже и сам министр, то "из".

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что раз Министерство — не живой человек, а учреждение, то *"от"* нельзя сказать, остаётся *"**из** Министерства финансов".*

Comment: Но дотации ведь получают от государства, пусть даже из бюджета.

Comment: Ну, тут другой смысл: от = со стороны государства. Случаи всё-таки разные.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно "из"! Примеры: из суда, из налоговой, из школы, из бани... От мамы, от деда, от учителя, от президента... "Из" - из определённого места, "от" - от личности.

Answer (score 0):

Контекста не хватает.
В целом в разных ситуациях возможно и так и эдак, но в деловой переписке более вероятен случай "от".

Прежде всего. Министерство скорее всего здесь выступает как юридическое лицо, поэтому довод, что "от" бывает только от конкретного лица, в общем-то снимается.

Понятно, что когда отправителем является не министерство (переслали, например, как циркулярку или это была просто рабочая переписка), то "от" невозможно. В остальных случаях, полагаю, "от" предпочтительнее, уже потому, что так в делопроизводстве отмечают всю входящую корреспонденцию. Да и на бланке предприятия/оранизации их название обязательно присутствует в явном виде.

При этом все сказанное имеет силу в отношении более или менее официальных текстов, на бланке с подписью и печатью. Если же речь идет о каких-то рабочих переговорах министерства или его сотрудников, то там большой роли не играет, можно и так и так сказать.

Answer (score 0):

Получить персональное письмо **от** Министерства финансов - случай *фантастический*: для этого потребовалось бы, чтобы обращение в тексте письма было буквально от имени министерства в целом (напр. "Министерство ф. обращается к Вам с просьбой профинансировать его в полном объёме..."), в лице каких-нибудь полномочных представителей, наделённых правом делать такие обращения. Адресатом могло бы быть исключительно влиятельное лицо, напр. миллиардер-филантроп или представитель высшей власти. Письмо же **из** Министерства - вполне нормально: какой-бы чиновник ни написал его на бланке, оно будет **из министерства** (либо *от* него лично, либо *из* конкретного подразделения м. *за* его личной подписью).